# How to use Filter and Map Haskell?

Tags: haskell

First of all sorry for my Englisch, I am new in Haskell and i dont really know much about it.

I want all even Numbers from [0..6] and then the square Numbers from them. Like this

`` a x = [ x * x | x <- [0 .. 6], x `mod` 2 == 0, x > 0] ``

but with map and filter.

i tried this one, but i dont know where i can put the `x*x` in there

`` amap x = map'(\x -> (filter'(\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0 && x > 0)[0..6])) [1,2] ``

the ouput of this is [[2,4,6]]

Comment: What is `[1,2]` doing here?

Comment: without it, i will get this error = <interactive>:1:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show ([a20] -> [[Integer]]))
        arising from a use of `print'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: yes, because `map` expects a list, the list that is produced by `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should map the *result* of the filter, expression like:

```
map (\x -> x*x) (filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0 && x > 0) [0..6])
```

`filter (\x -> x`mod`2 == 0 && x > 0) [0..6]` will thus return a list of items that are even and greater than `0`, then we can use `map` to map each element of that list `x` to `x*x`.